# What requirements are there for cross-referencing a Python object in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, cross-reference

I'm using `:class:` and getting a lot of warnings

> `WARNING: py:class reference target not found: mypkg.submodule.class`.

I can't find anywhere in the documentation what exactly the requirements are for a correct cross-reference.

This is currently an incomplete list of requirements I think there are:

- The module of the object needs to be importable
- The object needs to exist inside of the module
- The object needs to be documented somewhere else in the build with a `:py:class::`, `:py:func::` or similar directive

  - This directive can be generated by the `autodoc` extension, in which case the object needs to have a docstring associated to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something to be cross-referenced it has to first be **"declared"**.

> The Python domain (name py) provides the following directives for module [**declarations**](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#the-python-domain):

There are 2 cases to consider:

- [domain directives](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#the-python-domain) (`.. domain:directive_name::`) and
- [roles](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects) (`:domain:role_name:`).

The case of `:class:` you specify is actually the shortened syntax of writing the role `:py:class:` not to be confused with the directive **declaration** `.. py:class::`.

> This directive can be generated by the autodoc extension, in which case the object needs to have a docstring associated to it.

The directive declarations are done implicitly by autodoc, but for objects without docstrings to be declared by autodoc you must use [`:undoc-members:` option with the autodoc directives](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directives).

> Members without docstrings will be left out, unless you give the undoc-members flag option:
>
> ```
> .. automodule:: noodle    
>    :members:    
>    :undoc-members:
> ```

One effect of **declaring** an object is that it is inserted in the index. So you can check the index to make sure it has been declared and inserted. (However note that [labels used in referencing arbitrary locations](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5/markup/inline.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations) are not inserted in the index.)

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper by default on your main page (usually index.html that corresponds to index.rst) there's a link called index that Sphinx automatically generates and manages for you.